# Могут ли сторонние приложения получить ту историю геолокации (или других наших действий ) устройства которое было до их установки?

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung

Мы знаем, что службы геолокации и OC всегда получают и хранят информацию о нашей геолокации и всех наших операциях. И после установки любое приложение может получить геолокационные и другие данные от ОС с помощью API.
Мой вопрос:
А может приложение получит те данные которые были перед его установкой? ОС предоставляет такую информацию?
и
2 вопрос :
Может  приложение сотрудничить например с приложениями погод и получить историю местоположения устройства перед его установкой .